# How can I pass argument with requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

In the main program I randomly choose an object which I'd like to animate, so I call the function with the object as the argument. The first loop is okay, `x` is finely set, but in the next turn it becomes `undefined`.

Something like this:

```
var anim = {
        mainFunc: function(x) {
            anim.update(x);
            anim.redraw(x);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(anim.mainFunc);
        },

        update: function(x) {

        },

        redraw: function(x) {

        }
};

var n=Math.floor(Math.random() * (ArrayOfAnimObject.length));
anim.mainFunc(ArrayOfAnimObject[n]);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You either need to create a reference or wrap the function call in another function like so:

```
mainFunc: function(x) {
    anim.update(x);
    anim.redraw(x);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        anim.mainFunc(x);
    });
}
```

Comment: why is it that 'x' is not passed explicitly like so: `window.requestAnimationFrame(function(x) {
            anim.mainFunc(x);`

Comment: Because the `x` in the callback function in your example is not what was passed in to the surrounding function. `requestAnimationFrame` is only passing a timestamp to the function it calls.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
mainFunc: function(x) {
    anim.update(x);
    anim.redraw(x);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim.mainFunc.bind(anim,x));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The best is probably to avoid having to do it.

The solutions that would allow you to do this will require that you create a new Function (be it the anonymous wrapper from @kalley's answer, or the bound one from @ArchyWillHe's) **every frame**.

In an animation loop, you want to leave the less collectable objects as possible, so that the Garbage Collector doesn't have to kick in while your animation is running, killing a few frames when it will happen.

In order to perform this, you have different strategies available, but for instance in the case exposed in OP, this `x` parameter should probably be attached to the `anim` object directly:

```js
var anim = {
  mainFunc: function() {
    anim.update();
    anim.redraw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.mainFunc);
  },

  update: function() {
    this.x ++;
  },

  redraw: function() {
    log.textContent = this.x;
  }
};
// replace it with a bound function only once
anim.mainFunc = anim.mainFunc.bind(anim);
anim.x = 0; // attach the parameter to the anim object
anim.mainFunc();
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

One may also prefer just keeping this parameter as a variable available for both the caller and `anim`:

```js
(function() {

var anim = {
  mainFunc: function() {
    anim.update();
    anim.redraw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim.mainFunc);
  },

  update: function() {
    x ++;
  },

  redraw: function() {
    log.textContent = x;
  }
};
var x = 0; // available for both us and anim's method
anim.mainFunc();

})();
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

10 years ago!
Here is how I do it: Attach the 2nd function to the animate function:

```
  let nloop=0, nfunc=0;
  animate.func = func1; // attach func1 to animate
  animate();
function animate() {
  if (animate.func) animate.func(); // call the attached function
  // or just "animate.func();" if something is always attached
  document.body.innerHTML = ++nloop +', ' + nfunc;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
function func1() { // the attached function
  nfunc += 1; 
}
```