# Adding additional arguments to a function called back by requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I am looking to create a function that scrolls an image element x pixels over y time on an HTML5 canvas, using requestAnimationFrame and delta time. What I can't figure out is how to add more arguments to my function, when requestAnimationFrame allready calls back my function with one argument (a DOMHighResTimeStamp). I am pretty sure the following code doesn't work:

```
function scroll(timestamp, distanceToScroll, secondsToScroll) {
  //delta = how many milliseconds have passed between this and last draw
  if (!lastDraw) {var lastDraw = timestamp;};
  delta = (0.5 + (timestamp - lastDraw)) << 0; //bitwise hack for rounding integers
  lastDraw = timestamp;

  //speed (pixels per millisecond) = amount of pixels to move / length of animation (in milliseconds)
  speed = distanceToScroll / secondsToScroll;

  //new position = current position + (speed * delta)
  position += (speed * delta);

  context.drawImage(myImage,0,position,50,50/*of 200*/,0,0,100,100);
  requestAnimationFrame(scroll(timestamp, distanceToScroll, secondsToScroll));
};

//later...
scroll(timestamp, 100, 5)
scroll(timestamp, 10, 20)
```

My question is I have no idea how to force requestAnimationFrame to continute to call my scroll function with my additional parameters, when all it does by default is pass just one argument (a timestamp) on callback. So how do I go about adding more parameters (or forcing rAF to put the timestamp in my 'timestamp' argument)?

Comment: From what I can muster with my limited knowledge, I think the solution lies either in .call()/.apply() or by passing an anonymous function that contains scroll in it to rAF, but I can't wrap my head around accessing rAF's timestamp if I do either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i pass argument with requestAnimationFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893336/how-can-i-pass-argument-with-requestanimationframe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**What your `requestAnimationFrame` statement evaluates to**:

- `scroll(timestamp, distanceToScroll, secondsToScroll)`, where timestamp is undefined. It throws an error or returns undefined
- `window.requestAnimationFrame` is executed without parameters, thus no callback

Passing an anonymous function that calls `scroll` with the desired parameters should do the trick:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
    scroll(timestamp, distanceToScroll, secondsToScroll));
});
```

**What this evaluates to:**

- `window.requestAnimationFrame` is called with anonymous function as callback
- anonymous function is called with `timestamp` as first parameter
- `scroll` is called with current `timestamp`, `distanceToScroll` and `secondsToScroll` as parameters

Comment: Such an obvious solution, but I couldn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame(timestamp=>scroll(timestamp, distanceToScroll, secondsToScroll));

Comment: but how would you to remove the requestAnimationFrame if there is no reference to an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript**

```
function scrollIntoViewSmooth(elem) {
    var move = elem.offsetTop - (elem.offsetTop - elem.parentElement.scrollTop) * 0.25;

    if (Math.abs(elem.offsetTop - move) <= 2) {
        elem.parentElement.scrollTop = elem.offsetTop;
    } else {
        elem.parentElement.scrollTop = move;
        setTimeout(scrollIntoViewSmooth, 33, elem);
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
scrollIntoViewSmooth(document.getElementById('stuff'));
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is javascript and alot better and recommended approach when working with animations, nothing goes more smoother