# Object turns into number when passed as argument

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing

I am quite new to this and just stumbled across this strange thing:

I am using the function `requestAnimationFrame` and have to pass an object as an argument. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061025/adding-additional-arguments-to-a-function-called-back-by-requestanimationframe) showed me how to pass an argument to the callback function, however when i pass an object, within the function it turns into a (seemingly random) number:

```
var myObj = {name : "Sanchez",  surname: "Pedro"};

console.log("outside", myObj);          // shows me the object
console.log("outside", typeof(myObj));  // object

requestAnimationFrame(function(myObj) {

    console.log("inside", myObj);          // shows me a random number
    console.log("inside", typeof(myObj));  // number
    // doSomethingToPedro(myObj)

});
```

[(see jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/smr97vx9/2/)

My Question now is, (A) how can i properly pass my object to the callback, and (B) why does this happen?

Comment: requestAnimationFrame sends HD time as argument. Also inside callback, myObj is pointing to argument and not to variable outside

Comment: The values to arguments are assigned when invoking a function, not when defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When JavaScript calls your callback it passes [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) time as first argument, and `myObj` in your example is this argument, that's why it's a number. This is mentioned in the docs:

> A parameter specifying a function to call when it's time to update
>   your animation for the next repaint. The callback has one single
>   argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time (the
>   time returned from Performance.now() ) for when requestAnimationFrame
>   starts to fire callbacks.

The way you code is structured, you don't need to pass `myObj` into callback, since it'll be accessible through closure mechanism anyway:

```
var myObj = {name : "Sanchez",  surname: "Pedro"};
requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp) {
    doSomethingToPedro(myObj) // I'm accessible through closure
});
```

If you still want to have object explicitly passed, you can use `bind` function to bind parameters:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function(myObj, timestamp) {
    doSomethingToPedro(myObj) // I'm accessible through bound value
}.bind(null, myObj));
```

Comment: so simple and so perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept it if answers your question :). I also provided two solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `requestAnimationFrame()`, you are **not** passing the `myObj` global object in the callback, you are actually setting the parameter name as `myObj` accessible only in the callback function scope, which is of type [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) according to the [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) documentation.