# Function.prototype.bind() not accepting more than 5 arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create some animations (in typescript), and I have a class that has methods that deal with them. For example for a fade in animation, I am using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` at the end of the method so that it can call itself. But because it is a method not a function, I need to use bind to set the correct context when using 'this'. The code that works:

```
private fade_in(glyph_sequence: PixelGlyphSequence, steps: number, color_delta: number, ending_animation: EndingAnimation)
    {
        // ... irrelevant stuff
    
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.fade_in.bind(this, glyph_sequence, steps, color_delta, ending_animation)); 
    }
```

The problem is that the bind method is not accepting more than 5 args! If i put 6, it gives me this error:

```
Argument of type '(...args: PixelGlyphSequence[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FrameRequestCallback'.   Types of parameters 'args' and 'time' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'PixelGlyphSequence
```

But I need to be able to pass another parameter, I don't understand why with 6 arguments, it expects everything to be the type of the first.
Why is this happening and what is a clean way to fix it without using global variables?
Also, is there any significant performance penalty for using bind in such a tight timeframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Complete side note, but it's a *terrible* idea to have 6 positional arguments to a function. Pass a (typed) object with named properties. Added bonus: won't confuse the compiler. As for perf, this is probably better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55840787/3757232